# How to set dbms_session.set_identifier from Entity Framework

Tags: oracle11g, entity

I am trying to implement audit trail in a web application that is backed by an Oracle Database, we do have  audit trail triggers in place that work flawlessly, when user alters data either via SQL client like TOAD or when I manually use Oracle.DataAccess.Client via

```
        // rest omitted for brevity // 

        var command = new OracleCommand();
        command.Connection = conn;


        var useridsql = new StringBuilder();

        useridsql.AppendLine("BEGIN");
        useridsql.AppendLine("dbms_session.set_identifier('username');");
        useridsql.AppendLine("END;");



        command.CommandText = useridsql.ToString();

        command.ExecuteNonQuery(); 
     // Rest of the insert / update / delete code //
```

What doesn't work is when I try to do the same by overriding SaveChanges() in DbContext class.

I assume that Entity is using a different from the above ADO.NET example on how it manages its connections and hence the reason that the update is happening but on a wrong Database session hence the dbms_session is not visible to the trigger.

I did try turning connection pooling off, that wasnt much of help either.

I have tried all possible scenarios known to me but without any success.

Does anyone here have an idea and could push me in the right direction.

Thanks in advance, your help is much appreciated.

with kind regards,

Max.

Answer (score 3):

I also tried what you did but in a trace I could see clientid was being reset to an empty string. Here is what worked for me.

My DbContext

```
private SiSiEntities db = new SiSiEntities();
```

I thought in doing the following it would be a different session but it works.

```
OracleConnection conn = db.Database.Connection as Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleConnection;
conn.Open();
conn.ClientId = User.Identity.Name.ToString().ToLower(); 
db.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: thanks! I've spent hours looking for a way to get a reference to the oracle connection

Answer (score 0):

In Spring you can extend the [TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/2.5.6/api/org/springframework/jdbc/datasource/TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy.html). You can override the *getConnection()* method and on fetching a connection, you can run the query to assign the database session to your current application session user. Of course this is only pertinant if you use transnational contexts.

To make things more efficient, you can also extend the Connection object to wrap it with the current session user's information so that you only update the database session user if it is different than the current user.

A simple example:

```
public class CustomTransactionAwareDataSourceProxy extends
        TransactionAwareDataSourceProxy {

    private static final SQL = "begin dbms_session.set_identifier(?); end;";

    public CustomTransactionAwareDataSourceProxy(
            final DataSource targetDataSource) {
        super(targetDataSource);
    }

    @Override
    public Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
        return this.decorate(super.getConnection());
    }

    private Connection decorate(final Connection conn)
            throws SQLException {

            try (PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareCall(SQL)) {
                statement.setString(1, this.getUsername());
                statement.execute();
            }
            return connection;
    }
}
```